# cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Player *' to 'Player' c++

Tags: c++

First of, I'm very new to c++, and i have tried looking around for this with no luck.

I am making a Rock, Paper, Scissors game as a c++ assignment.
In my main i would like to instantiate my obejcts / classes
Here is my Main.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Match.h"
#include "ComputerAI.h"
Player* player;
ComputerAI* ai;
Match* match;

int main()
{
    player = new Player();
    ai = new ComputerAI();
    match = new Match(player, ai);

    match->StartMatch();

    while(true)
    {
        match->StartNewRound();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting is at Match(player, ai)

```
Error 2 error C2664: 'Match::Match(Player,Player)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Player *' to 'Player'
```

The overloaded constructor for Match looks like this:

```
Match(Player player1, Player player2);
```

I think i know what the mistake is, since it basicly says i cant convert from a pointer to a non pointer, but i have no clue how to solve it.

If i change the constructor to:

```
Match(Player* player1, Player* player2);
```

It is happy but that just gives me 100 new problems.

Hope you guys can help me out.

If you need i can link the full classes but wasn't sure you would need it.

Comment: C++ is not Java or C#. Your code should not be littered with `new`s, especially not in the example you gave.

Comment: Nothing wrong with new provided you have an object like shared_ptr taking ownership.

Comment: Do not write "(SOLVED)" in the title. Instead accept one of the answers.

Comment: Use the big checkmark at the left side of the answer that solved your problem to accept.

Comment: @Pete: Even in that case, you should be using `make_shared`, rather than using `new` directly.

Comment: @Spook first post didn't know how :D Fixed now and answer accepted.

Comment: @Pete: a lot is wrong with `new` when you use it where objects may instead simply be created on the stack, even with smart pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that you don't really need pointers here. Try this:

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Match.h"
#include "ComputerAI.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // Avoid global variables. Move them
    // as local main variables.
    Player player;
    ComputerAI ai;
    Match match;

    match.StartMatch();

    while(true)
    {
        match.StartNewRound();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Take into consideration, that if you accept `Player` as parameters to `Match` constructor, you'll get *copies* of passed instances instead of originals and I guess, that this is not, what you want. Try:

```
class Match
{
private:
    Player & first;
    Player & second;

public:
    Match(Player & newFirst, Player & newSecond)
        : first(newFirst), second(newSecond)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow.. Of all the things i tried why didn't i try this! Thanks you are a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
match = new Match( *player, ai );
```

or if the second parameter of the constructor also is not a pointer then

```
match = new Match( *player, *ai );
```

though in your code ai has no type Player *.

```
ai = new ComputerAI();
```

However I do not see a sense of the dynamically allocating of player in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment because I dont have enough reputation yet? But what errors does it give you if you make the match contructor:

```
Match(Player* player1, Player* player2)
```

?

I have a suspicion, but remember when its a pointer to call functions of that class you need to use the -> operator. So for example, `player1->makeMove();`

Comment: It seems, that whole `Match` class assumes, that `Player`'s are passed by value, and stores them internally in the same way. In such case changing ctor parameters (and then, in effect, type of private fields) will cause a lot errors.